# angular2 - Service value not changing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular, routes

I have a route called home and it has three child routes, documents, mail and trash. In the home route component it has a variable called 'myUser'. I created a service so they can all share the myUser value, but for some reason the service variable value doesn’t change. 

Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription }   from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Injectable()
export class HomeService {
  // Mock user, for testing  
  myUser = {name:"John", loggedIn:true};

  setUser(name:string){
    this.myUser.name = name ; 
  }

  isLogged():boolean {
    if(this.myUser.loggedIn == true){
      return true ; 
    }
    return false ; 
  }
}
```

Home (parent route)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
import { CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/common';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { contentHeaders } from '../common/headers';

import { HomeService } from '../../home.service';


const template = require('./home.component.html');
const styles = require('./home.component.css');

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  directives: [ CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES ],
  template: template,
  styles: [ styles ],
  providers: [HomeService]
})

export class HomeComponent {
  constructor(public router: Router, private homeService: HomeService) {

  }
  myUser = this.homeService.myUser ; 

  setUser(name:string){
    this.homeService.setUser(name); 
  }

  // Is logged in
  isLogged():boolean {
    return this.homeService.isLogged(); 
  }
}
```

Mail (child route)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/common';
import { HomeService } from '../../home.service';


const template = require('./mail.component.html');
const styles = require('./mail.component.css');

@Component({
  selector: 'mail',
  directives: [ CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES ],
  template: template,
  styles: [ styles ],
  providers: [HomeService]
})

export class MailComponent {
  constructor(public router: Router, private homeService: HomeService) {

  }

  myUser = this.homeService.myUser ; 

  setUser(name:string){
    this.homeService.setUser(name); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to inject `HomeService` into either `bootstrap` function in Dependency array or `MainComponent` providers so that service will instantiate only once.

```
bootstrap(MainComponent, [HomeService, ....other dependency...])
```

And then remove `HomeService` from `providers` array of both the components metadata.

Comment: @John you have to remove `HomeService` from `providers` array from both the `component`..

Comment: Yeah, I just saw your edit it works when i remove providers. Why is that?

Comment: @John because when you add it there, it re instantiate the `HomeService` instance..where as you wanted to use the firstly generated instance..thats why you shouldn't be injecting `HomeService` dependency there in providers array..

Comment: Okay, so i have to inject it into the main component providers. Should i create like a Main Service where all my services are, so i don't have to call so many services in my Main Component ?

Comment: No, don't create a new service. You have to include all the `services` to Providers array. That will solve an issue.

Comment: Thanks! By provies array you mean the bootstrap(...) right ?

Comment: I meantto say In both places.. either in provider or in bootstrap function

Comment: Well it works in the boostrap function. However, when i tired the  providers: [HomeService], it wasnt working. Hence my original question.

Comment: Is there maybe another issue going on here? I would rather call the HomeService in the providers than in the main component.

Comment: I think you got me wrong.. I already said either inject service once in bootstrap function OR MainComponent `providers` metadata options once..

Comment: So if you going for other way then you don't need to inject service in other component providers option.. like here you need to remove `HomeService` instance from both MailCompenent and HomeComponent

Comment: You must have to follow my last two comments to make service to provide singleton behavior

Comment: So let me just see if i understand. If i add it to bootstrap(..). I still have tot import it in all my components i use the service but, i don’t add it to the providers portion. If i do it in the main component ( but i don't know where), i don't have to import it in all the components that use it, am i correct?